# spark2-submit is throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am getting following error while running spark2-submit after installing spark 2.0.0.

Does anyone know why it is not able to point to hadoop jar files? When I '`echo $HADOOP_HOME`' in spark2-submit its shows the correct `HADOOP_HOME` path.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments$$anonfun$mergeDefaultSparkProperties$1.apply(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments$$anonfun$mergeDefaultSparkProperties$1.apply(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:118)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.mergeDefaultSparkProperties(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the jars in the HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop to the CLASSPATH.
Such as I add CLASSPATH in the /etc/profile,and my hadoop version is 2.7.2

```
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.2.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:$CLASSPATH
```